# Wifi missing on Ubuntu 16.04.3 - dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: wireless

I've got no wifi with my newly installed Ubuntu dual booted with Windows.

I'm new to Linux, and so I'm looking for a straightforward way to fix it. Please guide me through steps needed to find and solve the problem. Thanks.

**sudo lshw -class network**

```
sudo lshw -class network

*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: 08:62:66:dc:91:94
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7204000-f7204fff memory:f7200000-f7203fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7100000-f7107fff
```

**rfkill list all**

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to disable 'secure boot' from the bios setup.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1572659

and then, if needed `sudo apt-get install bcwm-kernel-source`

Comment: How can I disable secure boot? I don't see any optiond in BIOS.

Comment: Installing 'bcmwl-kernel-source' did it! Thanks! (You had it mistyped though.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Connect to LAN

1. Search for Additional Drivers
2. See if there are any Broadcom drivers available( Wait for some time if not available, it takes time to load available drivers some time )
3. If it already says, Using BroadCom Corporation .., click on 'donot use this device'-> Apply Changes, then again 'Use BroadCom Corporation...'-> Apply Changes
4. Restart your Ubuntu

Comment: What do you mean by connecting to LAN? I don't have wired connection. Also in Additional Drivers, Broadcom is already on "Don't use..."

Comment: If it is on Don't use, click on 'Use Broadcom....'. My point was to turning it off and turn it on again.If it off now, turn in on. WiFi should work

Comment: If you have internet on phone, connect it via USB and you can internet via USB

Comment: I had tried that before. The problem is that it stucks on 'apply change'.  and thanks for your last tip :)